# Search Results and Aggregate Results in a Single View ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my first ASP.NET Core project. I have a single page application where I have a search box and a button in the Index.cshtml page. If the search box text is empty then nothing is displayed else the records corresponding to pId is retrieved and displayed in the Index.cshtml page.So far this is working great.

I am looking to extend this view by aggregating the weight for a given day and display it at the top.So once the user enters a PId and submits the page, I would like to display

```
 pId    total_weight   create_dt
```

Below it, would be the current view which I already have

```
 pId   bIdc   rule_id   weight   create_dt
```

I am not sure where I should be aggregating the scores? How do I update my current view to display the aggregated values?

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index(string pId)
{
        var scores = from ts in _context.Scores
                          select ts;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pId))
        {
            scores = scores.Where(p => p.p_id.Equals(pId)).OrderByDescending(p => p.create_dt);

            return View(scores.ToList());
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div id="p-form">
<form asp-controller="Score" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        <b> P Id:</b> <input type="text" name="pId">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
</div>
@if (Model != null)
{
    <div id="p-scores">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.p_id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.b_idc)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rule_id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.weight)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.create_dt)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.p_id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.b_idc)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.rule_id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.weight)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.create_dt)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Did you try `GroupBy` method ?

Comment: Where would I use groupby?In the controller and how would I return that to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GroupBy method to group the data.

I would create a new class to represent the grouped data

```
public class WeightItemTotal
{
    public int PId { set; get; }
    public decimal TotalWeight { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { set; get; }
}
```

Now when you get data, first group by PId and for each item in that (each PId), group the results based on date and use the Sum method to get the Total Weight.

```
var resultGrouped = new List<WeightItemTotal>();

var pgrouped = _context.Scores.Where(c=>c.p_id==pId)
                               .GroupBy(a => a.PId);
foreach (var p in pgrouped)
{
    var grouped = p.GroupBy(f => f.CreatedDate, items => items, (key, val) 
                                                                  => new WeightItemTotal
    {
        PId = val.FirstOrDefault().PId,
        CreatedDate = key,
        TotalWeight = val.Sum(g => g.Weight)
    }).ToList();

    resultGrouped.AddRange(grouped);
}
return View(resultGrouped);
```

Now since we are returning the grouped result to the view, make sure it is strongly typed to that type

```
@model IEnumerable<WeightItemIotal>
<table>
@foreach(var p in Model)
{
  <tr>
      <td>@p.PId</td> 
      <td>@p.TotalWeight</td>
      <td>@p.CreatedDate</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I created a new class in model ScoreAgg, then populated it using the records and stored in ViewData["AggScores"], then used it in the view.That way I get both views i.e AggScores,Scores.